# Counting size of an array inside another JSON array: SQL SERVER

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2017

The JSON object structure is:

```
{
  "store": {
    "storeId":123,
    "operations": {
      "seasons": [
        {
          "storeHours": [{},{},{}]  // consider it has 3 objects
        },
        {
          "storeHours": [{},{}]  //consider it has 2 objects
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to count the size of `"storeHours"`. I tried with:

```
DECLARE @count INT = 0;
DECLARE @destination NVARCHAR = (N'$.store.operations.seasons[' +  @count +  N'].storeHours');
```

Also tried with:

```
DECLARE @destination NVARCHAR = CONCAT(N'$.store.operations.seasons[',  @count, N'].storeHours');

DECLARE @storeHoursCount INT = (
   select count(A.[key]) as [count] 
   from (VALUES(@json)) V(J)
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.J) WITH(
      [storeHours] nvarchar(MAX) @destination  AS JSON) S
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(S.storeHours) A
);
```

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@destination'

This works:

```
DECLARE @storeHoursCount INT = (
   select count(A.[key]) as [count] 
   from (VALUES(@json)) V(J)
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.J) WITH (
      [storeHours] nvarchar(MAX) '$.store.operations.seasons[0].storeHours' AS JSON
   ) S
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(S.storeHours) A
);
```

But I want it to be dynamic. Is there something that I am missing? Also what can be the reason for `CONCAT()` not working?

**EDIT:**
@Zhorov solution works really good when we want over all count of storeHours present. i.e Sum of all storeHours present in all seasons.

My requirement is to get count of storeHours based upon index season (eg: season[0]).
How can this be achieved?

Comment: `seasons` is also a JSON array, so you have nested JSON arrays. Which count do you want?

Comment: The inner one, ```storeHours```

Comment: Why are you using JSON like that instead of proper tables? Shop working hours is a pretty mundane, static schema. Using JSON only adds delays, not flexibility

Comment: I am sending a JSON from Mule 4. It is quite flexible to work with JSON on that platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**

If I understand you correctly and you want to count all items in all nested `$.storeHours` arrays, the following approach is an option:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @count INT = 0;
DECLARE @destination nvarchar(max) = N'
{
  "store": {
    "storeId":123,
    "operations": {
      "seasons": [
        {
          "storeHours": []
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
FROM OPENJSON(@destination, '$.store.operations.seasons') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value], '$.storeHours') j2

SELECT @count
```

As an additional note, always specify the length of an `nvarchar` variable. When the length is not specified in a variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. In your case, the actual value of the `@destination` variable is simply `$`.

**Update:**

If you want to *...to get count of storeHours based upon index season ...*, simply use the appropriate `WHERE` clause:

```
DECLARE @count INT = 0;
DECLARE @destination nvarchar(max) = N'
{
  "store": {
    "storeId":123,
    "operations": {
      "seasons": [
        {
          "storeHours": [{},{},{}]
        },
        {
          "storeHours": [{},{}] 
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'

SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
FROM OPENJSON(@destination, '$.store.operations.seasons') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value], '$.storeHours') j2
WHERE CONVERT(int, j1.[key]) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, It helps. Also for the info related to ```nvarchar```

Comment: Hi @Zhorov, can you please go through the edited part and help me?

Comment: @SatyamPisal Check the updated answer. Thanks,